# Bz2 Decompression in C#

Tags: c#, compression

Im looking for an example of how to decompress a bz2 file. I download the file via a control flow in an SSIS package, I would like to kick off a Script Task using some C# code to decompress the downloaded bz2 file. It doesn't seem that the decompression library that comes with .net handles bz2 files. Could someone show me an implimentation that could? or direct me to an example of decompressing a bz2 file to a specified folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) comes with bzip2 support (and many many more formats) and a C# wrapper.

Answer (score 10):

[SharpZipLib](http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) is what you're looking for.

> #ziplib (SharpZipLib, formerly NZipLib) is a Zip, GZip, Tar and BZip2 library written entirely in C# for the .NET platform.